Troubles with this plot (tikz, pgfplots)
I wanted to draw a plot for arcsin function, and this is what I managed to compute so far
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{scrreport}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{total={173mm, 257mm}, margin=17mm}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{pspicture}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
 clip=false,
 xmin=-1.2,xmax=1.2,
 very thick,
 xlabel= \(\vu*{x}\),
 ylabel=\(\vu*{y}\),
 width=.9\textwidth,
        height=.5\textheight,
 ymin=-2.2,ymax=2.2,
 axis lines=middle,
 %axis x line=middle,
 %axis y line=left,
%     axis x line=middle,
 xtick={-1, 0, 1},
 ytick={-1.57, 0, 1.57},
 xticklabels={-1, 0, 1},
 yticklabels={-\(\frac{\pi}{2}\), 0,\(\frac{\pi}{2}\)},
 %xticklabel style={anchor=north west}
 ]
  \addplot[domain=-1:1,samples=300, magenta, very thick]    {asin(x)/180*pi};         
\end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{center}  
 



\end{document}

But there are many problems I would like to fix.

First of all, the plot is too large, I mean the draw. I couldn't manage to scale it properly, because if I add [scale=0.6] I obtain that the labels x-y on the axis appear elsewhere (didn't understand why)

π/2 and -π/2 look like too little as text size, how can I make them bigger in size?


Well, do you have some tips to improve this plot?
Thank you!


You have width=.9\textwidth, height=.5\textheight in the axis options, have you tried changing those?

@TorbjørnT.This is weird. I tried before, and I got a mess. I tried now again with different values, and I obtained a smaller plot. Weird... But thanks!

From all the packages you load you won’t need them all for this example. Comment out all, compile and uncomment step by step until it compiles. Chances are you’ve got unwanted interference.

start by commenting out physics, which is known to be ... problematic. are you compiling with xelatex?

You can use \dfrac instead of \frac, or even $\pi/2$.
